# Is it a violation of copyright law to sell a collage made from physically cut out and pasted materials?

Tags: copyright

I understand that I cannot copy an image, add it to a collage, and sell that collage, as it would violate copyright law. But what about repurposing physical copies? For instance, what if I cut out images, text, etc., from a magazine, and paste them on a board? Would selling this piece trigger copyright law?

As I see it, and perhaps the law sees it quite differently, I have not copied anything, and therefore do not trigger ***copy***rite action. I have simply reused an existing licensed piece in a new piece.

Comment: Copyright laws are often jurisdiction dependent. You will get a better answer if you specify a jurisdiction.

Answer (score 4):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)
The first sale doctrine, (17 U.S.C. § 109), allows one who legitimately purchases a copy of a copyrighted receives the right to sell, display or otherwise dispose of that particular copy, notwithstanding the interests of the copyright owner. However, it does not allow one to change it.

Under US law, doing so would create a derivative work, which would potentially violate copyright, but may indeed fall under the affirmative defense of "fair use" (which is determined on a case-by-case basis). (The rationale is that the first sale doctrine applies to a single article; one who makes a "fair use" derivative work can claim their own copyright, and thus make more copies).

The more "transformative" the derivative work, the better chance it stands of being found fair use. Merely ripping up a work, and reassembling it to form a "mosaic effect" is unlikely to pass muster, for example.

A derivative work that comments on the original work, especially social or political commentary, or on a sentiment strongly associated with the original work, is more likely to be deemed fair use. Painting polka dots the Statue of Liberty is unlikely to do well, whereas putting images of a political or social commentary nature on the Statue of Liberty is (for example, I believe I've seen one such with faces of individuals of a variety of ethnicities superimposed on the statue, making a statement of America (associated with the statue) and its history of immigration and multi-ethnic makeup). (Although the Statue of Liberty is very much not under copyright, for a number of reasons).

Another aspect is how much, and how central a portion, of the original work is used. Using the pedestal the Statue of Liberty stands on would probably be better than the statue its self, for example.

Comment: "However, it does not allow one to change it." I would not agree. You can do anything you want with that physical object even though you don't have the copyright. It isn't a derivative work just because something is made of pieces of something you own that you bought free of copyright limitations due to the first sale doctrine.

Comment: @ohwilleke I wouldn't be surprised if the Ninth did indeed see that as a derivative. As I point out in [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/57850/3209), mere fixation of an existing work on a new medium could constitute a derivative (the Seventh disagreed).

Comment: @ohwilleke: Source? I've cited my finding of the legal basis of the first sale doctrine (17 U.S.C. § 109), which only mentions selling, lending, displaying or otherwise transferring the individual artifact. There is no mentioning of alterations of the original artifact in 109, although 109 is a carve out of exemptions to the rights granted to copyright holders in 106, and 106(2) grants copyright holders an exclusive right to "to prepare derivative works based upon the copyrighted work".

Comment: @ohwilleke  As to if it is or isn't a derivative work, if one song sampling another song, even for a riff or chord(I'm not a musician, I may be using the terms wrong here), can give rise to a successful lawsuit's copyright infringement claim (which would require the second song to be a derivative work), it seems likely to me that using a portion of an image in another "image" (treating the collage as one collective image), can also be infringing.

Comment: @sharur The first sale doctrine doesn't apply to music recordings. So, unless you are using the old school technologies I did working at a college radio station, where we literally took a cassette tape we purchased, sliced it up with scissors, and spliced it together with tape, you can't rely on the first sale doctrine the way you can in a cut up object. Also, the first sale doctrine doesn't confer performance rights in the purchased work (you can't buy a CD and play it to a stadium of 10,000 people start to finish without paying a royalty), but performance rights aren't implicated by a mural.

Comment: Got some interesting conversations going here. I'm as puzzled as ohwilleke here. The idea that one can trigger copyright law, without actually copying anything, doesn't make sense. But since when did law have to make sense?  | Regarding @sharur's rebuttal, making a copy of the original and rearranging it is different than simply cutting up the original print and rearranging the pieces. The former creates a new copy. The latter does not.

Comment: @DanielGoldman IMO it makes sense if you disregard taking the word copyright literally. It's a poor word for it, most European jurisdictions prefer something along the lines of "author's rights" (once translated). Copyright law can cover many non-copying actions including modification, distribution, import/export, licensing, reverse engineering, circumventing technical restrictions, moral rights, etc. though many jurisdictions consider the latter legally distinct from copyright itself.